# sshfs in fstab connection reset with ssh tunnel in ~/.ssh/conf when 'manual' command works fine

Tags: fstab, ssh-tunneling, sshfs, ssh-config

I'm trying to set up an sshfs mount in fstab for persistent mounting of a network directory that has to be accessed via an ssh tunnel.

my `.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
Host A
    Hostname outer.server
    User <user>
    IdentityFile /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
    ForwardAgent yes

Host B
    Hostname inner.server
    User <user>
    IdentityFile /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh -q A "nc %h %p"
    ForwardAgent yes
```

This works fine:

```
sshfs B:/home/<user>/ /mnt/B
```

In fstab this does not

```
sshfs#B:/home/<user>/    /mnt/B      fuse.sshfs      defaults,idmap=user,allow_other,reconnect,_netdev,users 0       0
```

and, when `mount -a` is run after updating `fstab` to put the changes into effect returns:

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I'd welcome any suggestions as to why the fstab version might not be working.

Comment: I suspect maybe mounting from `fstab` basically uses root's (and/or global) ssh config to actually connect, regardless of other user-related options. I cannot confirm at the moment. The config you pasted is your regular user's config, right? Make the relevant fragment applicable to `ssh` initiated by root. Any progress?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Assuming placing a copy of `~/.ssh/config` in `/.ssh/config` should mean root initiated `ssh` commands have the same ssh tunnel set up as my user, this does not appear to have made any difference.

Comment: Does `sshfs B:/home/<user>/ /mnt/B` work as the normal user and also as root?

Comment: No `sudo sshfs B:/home/<user>/ /mnt/B` is also giving me connection reset error. I'm using absolute paths for everything so there shouldn't be any `~` user vs root home issues. So maybe setting `/.ssh/config` is not affecting the root ssh - if not I don't know how to change the ssh config for the root user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root does not see your per-user ssh configuration file. You need to place it in the root home directory (`/root/`) or into the system-wide configuration file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, assuming the authentication key is not encrypted (does not have passphrase).

You can also save a lot of trouble by throwing away the netcat and using the -W switch for IO forwarding directly in SSH or if you have new-enough OpenSSH, you can use just the ProxyJump option (see the manual for details).

And remove also the `ForwardAgent yes`. You do not need it for anything and it is just exposing your private keys to the server.

Comment: Thanks - forgot root's home was `/root` and not just in `/` when I set up the `.ssh/config` duh! I also had to drop the `sshfs#` from the beginning of my `fstab` lines for it to work.